# Trouble Understanding Holm-Bonferroni Correction

Tags: multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I have a bit of trouble understanding the Holm-Bonferroni correction.
For the normal Bonferroni correction you simply divide your alpha level by the number of tests. For example, if I have 3 tests, I will test all 3 test against a alpha level of .016. Note: I´m adjusting alpha instead of p, because I´m doing a power analysis.

Now, for the Holm-Bonferroni correction, I understood that you apply the Bonferroni correction sequentially. That is: Test 1: Alpha = .05. Test 2: Alpha = .025 Test 3: Alpha = .016. However, that seems to be incorrect. Consider the following code in R:

```
> pvalues <- c(0.049, 0.049, 0.049)
> p.adjust(pvalues, method = "holm")
[1] 0.147 0.147 0.147
> p.adjust(pvalues, method = "bonferroni")
[1] 0.147 0.147 0.147
```

Both methods return exactly the same output for all three p-values. Can anyone explain where I get the Holm-Bonferroni correction wrong and how I can adjust my alpha appropriately? Please note that the output remains identical with more p-values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm getting it wrong, but it seems that both methods return the same corrected p-values because the three original p-values are equal.

For the Bonferroni correction, you simply multiply each p-value by the number of p-values (here by $3$).

For the Holm-Bonferroni, first you need to sort the p-values and then multiply the smallest by $3$, then the second one by $2$ etc.
But if at one step the corrected p-value is smaller than the previous one, then it is made equal to it (this sentence is only based on empirical constatations using the `p.adjust` function).

For example, say your (sorted) p-values are $(0.1,0.11,0.5)$.
The first one is multiply by $3$: $0.1 \leftarrow 0.3$, the second one by $2$: $0.11 \leftarrow 0.22$.
But since $0.22 < 0.3$, the corrected p-value for the second one will be $0.3$.  For the third you multiply by $1$.
The corrected p-values are then $(0.3,0.3,0.5)$.

I think this is what happens here, since all the p-values are equal you have the first one multiplied by $3$ which gives $0.147$, the second one by $2$ which gives $0.098$. Since $0.098 < 0.147$, actually the corrected p-value for the second one will be $0.147$. The same goes for the third one.

Then all the three corrected p-values will be the same (and equal to those given by the Bonferroni correction since the have been multiplied by $3$).

If you use different p-values, the Holm method should give you something different than the Bonferroni method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I understood it now. However, your last sentence is incorrect: It will give you the same p-value if the differences are small.

> pvalues <- c(0.048, 0.047, 0.049)
> p.adjust(pvalues, method = "holm")
[1] 0.141 0.141 0.141
> p.adjust(pvalues, method = "bonferroni")
[1] 0.144 0.141 0.147
>